# How i can used chunk to reproduce my design perfectly with my column and flex?

Tags: css, reactjs

i have this design to reproduce

[image]

for the moment with my code i did this

[image]

i struggle to put the second column on the opposit way to the other , i think i need to play with the index of the column ? I also need to add a button see more and reproduce this mosaic in a dynamic way

jsx :

```
const mosaic = () => {
    const chunkArray = (arr, chunkSize) => {
      const chunkedArr = [];
      let index = 0;

      while (index < arr.length) {
        chunkedArr.push(arr.slice(index, index + chunkSize));
        index += chunkSize;
      }

      return chunkedArr;
    };

    const columnData = chunkArray(imageUrls, 2);

    return (
      <div className="mosaic">
        {columnData.map((column, columnIndex) => (
          <div className="column" key={columnIndex}>
            {column.map((imageUrl, index) => (
              <div
                className={`item ${index === 0 ? "large" : "small"}`}
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})` }}
                key={index}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

css:

```
.mosaic {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.small {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.large {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .column {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```